# Adding React-Slick CSS leads to conflict with Tailwind CSS and destroy base style by tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[I'm React and Tailwind newbie and this is my first time asking question here].

I have coded a movie-app using tailwind css, after all things done, I added React-Slick in to the Main.Js (Hero section) and it turns out ruining the beautiful style that I have made.

Please help! thanks in advance.

**source code**: https://github.com/trantrunghieuvns/netflix1.11/tree/fixbugs

**deployed web:** https://comfy-zuccutto-c43c67.netlify.app/

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck